# Unable to get radio group value via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a radio group which is contains 2 radio buttons. This radio group created after an `Ajax` response. I want to get the value of the checked radio button but i am unable to do this. Here is my implementation, any help would be appriciated.

HTML:

```
Yes<input class='radioInput' id='g1Positive' type='radio' name='g1' value='YES'/>
No<input class='radioInput' id='g1Negative' type='radio' name='g1' value='NO'/>
```

JS:

```
$('#resultTable').on("click", ".editForm2", function(){
   var isIengStuWork = $('input:radio[name=g1]:checked').val();
});
```

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please?

Comment: @j08691 what do you mean by complete ?

Comment: I mean show us what your HTML is so that we can recreate the issue.

Comment: What has the class `editForm2` and what has the ID `resultTable`? It would be helpful to see that part of your HTML. I made an example guessing at how your page is setup at http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uujw2b9f/, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s26frdjg/) is the answer

As you didn't post the html I just display the value in a div when a button is clicked

Html

```
<input [value][2]="first" type="radio" name="foo">First
<input value="second" type="radio" name="foo">Second
<input value="third" type="radio" name="foo">Third

<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS

```
$("#show").click(function() {
    var value = $('input[name=foo]:checked').val();
    $('#result').html(value);
});
```

UPDATE

After your comment I wonder if you're element with id "resultTable" would be a dynamically loaded one as the radio buttons. In that case that binding wouldn't work.
You should be reference there an already existing element in the DOM, a static element let's say. Although you could still be dynamically loading the element with class "editForm2"
More information on http://api.jquery.com/on/

That would be something like this

```
$('#staticParentElement').on('click', '#dynamicChildElement', function(){ //whatever });
```

I have created this [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s26frdjg/3/). In it I mimic the ajax addition of elements to the DOM by displaying a button that adds content

In the first case I just add the content inside the table to an existing container, to which I bind the click event of the "show" button

So we add the radio buttons and the show button to a static #staticTable

```
<div id="staticTable"></div> <br/>
<button id="addStatic">Add dynamic content into static Table</button><br/>

$("#addStatic").click(function() {
    $('#staticTable').append("Dynamic content into static table<br/>Yes<input class='radioInput' id='g1Positive' type='radio' name='g1' value='YES'/>No<input class='radioInput' id='g1Negative' type='radio' name='g1' value='NO'/><button class='show'>Show</button>");
});
```

And then we are able to bind the show button click like this

```
$("#staticTable").on('click', '.show', function() {
    var value = $(':radio[name=g1]:checked').val();
    $('#staticResult').html(value);
});
```

This works

But if we were adding to the DOM the "container" we are binding to, it wouldn't work. In the fiddle for example we inject a #dynamicTable inside a div

```
<div id="ContainerForDynamicTable"></div><br/>
<button id="addDynamic">Add dynamic Table</button><br/><br/>

$("#addDynamic").click(function() {
   $('#ContainerForDynamicTable').append("Dynamic table<br/><div id='dynamicTable'>Yes<input class='radioInput' id='g1Positive'type='radio' name='g1' value='YES'/>No<input class='radioInput' id='g1Negative' type='radio'name='g1' value='NO'/></div><button class='show'>Show</button>");
});
```

and we try to bind the show button click selecting that #dynamicTable

```
$("#dynamicTable").on('click', '.show', function() {
    var value = $(':radio[name=g1]:checked').val();
    $('#dynamicResult').html(value);
});
```

This doesn't work

Notice that for making the last one we should find a static parent of the .show button, in this case the closest in the upwards tree would be #ContainerForDynamicTable (you can even go up until document although it would be more costly to find later the .show button)

Comment: This does not work. Please notice that my radio group comes as a result of an Ajax request.

Comment: And the resultTable you are binding to? is it dynamically added as well? Guess you know you should refer to a static ancestor

Comment: @Tartar, I reckon your problem was binding to a dynamically loaded element, check my update. Am I right and solves your issue?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$('#resultTable').on("click", ".editForm2", function(){
var checked_ele = $('input[type="radio"][name="g1"]:checked');
 $(checked_ele).each(function(){
   // do stuff here
 });
});
```